# How to reorder the date in a view expose filter?

Tags: views, datetime

I have created a view with date expose filter. Currently filter is working fine but i need to reorder the day and month.

From **month/day/year**

[image]

To **day/month/year**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the settings **Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language**

Comment: I think you should add some more details about the actual settings "there", and also explain how to adapt them ... Just a suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form_alter to accomplish without any date format change from configuration. The example is below.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_name') {
      // alter your exposed form here
      $form['date_filter']['value']['#date_format'] = 'd-M-Y';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vgoradiya for your suggestion. Currently i am able to solve my issue from settings. But i will definitely check this answer and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: No issues. Actually I already implement and suggest the same code.